# For what reason does Top Questions have a different appearance to All Questions?

Tags: discussion, design

Is it simply to draw a distinction between which list you're looking at?

I find the Top Questions layout particularly hard to use, especially on a cellphone, but it does seem to be the layout that harks back to the origins of SO:

[image]

[image]

Comment: All I see is the +448 rep notifcation. How do you resist the temptation?

Comment: @kemicofa it's possible that resisting the temptation over time that lead to eventually having +448

Comment: Yeah.. I've still not figured out what that is

Comment: I am not using SO on mobile and on the desktop browser I prefer the Top questions layout. Still I find it confusing two different layouts are used which are quite similar, and there is no obvious reason why they are not the same.

Comment: Tagged with `lack-of-design` :p